# trim an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

i'm trying to understand sorting better and i'm running into a problem with the java.lang.NullPointerException i know it's because of the null values in the array.  so my question is, is there an easy way to remove those null values or trim the array so there won't be that error?  any feedback would be most appreciated

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args){
      person[] persons = new person[6];
    persons[0]=new person("bill nye",34);
    persons[1]=new person("frank white",64);
    persons[2]=new person("sara poppa ",20);
    persons[3]=new person("jess stoor",28);
    persons[4]=new person("mike amato",20);




    for(int i=0;i<persons.length;i++){ //before sorting
    System.out.println(persons[i]);
    }

    insertionSort(persons);
    System.out.println();

    for(int i=0;i<persons.length;i++){ //before sorting
        System.out.println(persons[i]);
    }

}
     public static void insertionSort(person[] persons) {
            int in, out;

            for (out = 1; out < persons.length; out++) {
              person temp = persons[out];
              in = out;

              while (in > 0 && persons[in - 1].getName().compareTo(temp.getName()) > 0) {
                  persons[in] = persons[in - 1];
                  --in;
                }
                persons[in] = temp;
              }
            }
```

}

```
public class person {
private String Name;
private int Age;
public person(String name, int age){

this.Name=name;
this.Age=age;


}   
    public String getName(){
    return Name;    
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }




    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        Age = age;
    }


    public String toString(){

        return Name + " " + Age;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're putting five objects in an array with a length of 6. Why not just create a smaller array?

Comment: `if(object.get(index)==null) remove(index)` If you run this conditional in a loop it should work'

Comment: i'm sorry this might be a dumb question i do understand the if statement but how would i remove said index?

Comment: Doesn't work for arrays, only works for lists.

Answer (score 3):

There are two easy solutions:

As suggested by Mureinik, you can just create the array to be one size smaller.

```
person[] persons = new person[5];
```

You also mention wanting to remove an index from the array, but you can't technically do this in `Java`.  You can `null` the values, but you can't actually remove the index.  If this is functionality you want long term, to dynamically handle array sizes, then you should use an `ArrayList` or `List` object.

```
ArrayList<person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
persons.add(object);
```

And if you needed to remove an object:

```
persons.remove(index);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try to keep the size of the array as small as possible to avoid these errors. 
Or just use an `ArrayList<person>`, which would totally eliminate these errors while having a relatively small performance impact.

```
List<person> persons = new ArrayList<person>();
persons.add(new person("John Smith", 42));
persons.add(new person("Jane Smith", 31));
```

If you still want to use an array you could use following options:

The trivial approach would be to count the non-null objects and copy them into a new array:

```
int nonNullCount = 0;
for (person p : persons)
    if (p != null)
        nonNullCount++;
person[] nonNullPersons = new person[nonNullCount];
int i = 0;
for (person p : persons)
    if (p != null)
        nonNullPersons[i++] = p;
```

Or you could just use Java 8 streams to filter all non-null objects:

```
person[] nonNullPersons = Arrays.stream(persons)
            .filter(p -> p != null) //only keep non-null persons
            .toArray(person[]::new); //create new array of persons
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

You can do something like this:

```
private <T> T[] removeNullElements(T[] array) {
  array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);

  int i = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if(array[j] != null) {
      array[i++] = array[j];
    }
  }

  return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, i);
}
```

This loops through your array and will skip every null element.

It's not very efficient, I just pulled it out of some code from a few years ago -- but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the array without the use of a `List`, with the proper number of elements, without hard coding the number of elements, using the array initializer syntax:

```
person[] persons = new person[] {
    new person("bill nye",34),
    new person("frank white",64),
    new person("sara poppa ",20),
    new person("jess stoor",28),
    new person("mike amato",20)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just initialize the array with the values.

```
person[] persons = { new person("bill nye",34), new person("frank white",64),
                     new person("sara poppa ",20), new person("jess stoor",28),
                     new person("mike amato",20) };
```

Or I would recommend using an `ArrayList` and adding your objects to it.

```
ArrayList<person> persons = new ArrayList();
persons.add(new person("bill nye",34));
persons.add(new person("frank white",64));
persons.add(new person("sara poppa ",20));
persons.add(new person("jess stoor",28));
persons.add(new person("mike amato",20));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new java8 feature called Arrays.stream and using the lambda expression you can achieve it.

```
Arrays.stream(arr).filter(v -> v != 0).toArray();
```